# How to pass value from parent asp.net dropdownlist to textbox in popup using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

Hello i am failing to pass the value from dropdownlist in the parent aspx form to textbox in the child aspx form

Parent javascript
: The First script is to open the popup window

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var popup;
       function NewCustOpn() {
      popup = window.open("NewCustomer.aspx","Popup",toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=520,height=350,left = 250,top = 50");

 }
   </script>
```

This is the second script on the parent page to get the value of the dropdownlist

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function parentFunc()
    {
        return document.getElementById ("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>").value;
    }

  </script>
```

The child page javascript:

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function ()
    {

        if(window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed)  
        {
           var val = window.opener.parentFunc();
      var textbox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
           textbox.Value = val; 
        }
    }
    </script>
```

When the popup opens TextBox1 is empty.

Comment: Why not achieving this from the code behind directly??

Comment: have you check your console logs. just put debugger and try to find any problem in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, please advise how i may do it from code behind directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple. Just replace the below line from your child page's js function

```
textbox.Value = val;
```

to

```
textbox.value = val; // lowercase "v"
```

or justdo a direct assignment like this

```
document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value = val;
```

Or another possible solution would be to directly pass the required value from the `parent page` as a `querystring` value and you don't  need the js function in the popup page. The querystring value you can access it in child pages's page load event and assign it directly to the textbox.

**Your Parent js**

```
   function NewCustOpn() {
        var ddlvalue = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>").value;
        var popup = window.open("Popup.aspx?dropdownval=" + ddlvalue, "Popup", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=520,height=350,left = 250,top = 50");
    }
```

**And from you child page's code behind**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["dropdownval"])) {
         TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["dropdownval"];
     }
 }
```